# How to enable Auto Failover using Cloudformation for AWS Elasticache Redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

failover for AWS Elasticache Redis cluster.

I want to enable this
[image: Snapshot]

I checked the documentation, and all I see is this four variables.
[image: Snapshot]

i've read the documentation, but these don't seem to serve the purpose. Can someone help me how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-replicationgroup.html#cfn-elasticache-replicationgroup-automaticfailoverenabled):

```
Type: AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup
Properties: 
  AutomaticFailoverEnabled: true
```